# Python code and shell script: os.system('rm /tmp/g2u_*_'+self.PID+' 2>/dev/null')?

Tags: python, bash, shell

https://github.com/benoitfragit/google2ubuntu/blob/master/librairy/interface.py

```
# Initialisation des notifications
self.PID = str(os.getpid())
os.system('rm /tmp/g2u_*_'+self.PID+' 2>/dev/null')
os.system('python '+self.p+'librairy/osd.py '+self.PID+' &')

# on joue un son pour signaler le démarrage
os.system('play '+self.p+'resources/sound.wav &')
os.system('> /tmp/g2u_start_'+self.PID)
```

I didn't understand the function of this code block in google2ubuntu project. Please, can someone explain these lines?

I understand these lines actually, I have problem with the others:

```
os.system('python '+self.p+'librairy/osd.py '+self.PID+' &')
```

It is calling /librairy/osd.py python script with the Process ID of program.

```
os.system('play '+self.p+'resources/sound.wav &')
```

and it is playing this sound file: /resources/sound.wav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
os.system('rm /tmp/g2u_*_'+self.PID+' 2>/dev/null')
```

This removes a file named "/tmp/g2u_*_" followed by self.PID, and suppress any error reporting.

```
os.system('> /tmp/g2u_start_'+self.PID)
```

This generates the file mentioned above. It's a 0-length file, serving as some kind of flag.

Comment: What do you think about the function of these `/tmp/g2u_*_` and `/tmp/g2u_start_` I'm a newbie programmer, why a programmer generates a file in tmp directory?

Comment: @MehmetMertYidiran **/tmp** is writable for everyone, so the file generation won't fail. In my opinion, these file serves as some kind of _flag_, indicating "yes" or "no" about the program's status.